# How to generate a list with xml element as key and xml as value in scala

Tags: xml, scala, list

I have a stream of xml records which I process in scala using hadoopRDD and finally save in a single file
However I need to sort those XMLs based on certain attributes before saving them in output file.

I thought of creating List with xml value and xml like below

### Input

```
<Transaction>
    <eventid>1234<eventId/>
    <eventName>hello<eventName/>
    .......
<Transaction/>
<Transaction>
    <eventid>2345<eventId/>
    <eventName>hi<eventName/>
    .......
<Transaction/>
```

--- and so on

My idea is to create a list as **{(1234, xml1),(2345,xml2)....}** , sort on first element and save the second element to output file.

How can this be done in Scala , or is there a better approach to do this
Thanks in advance for your suggestions and help

Comment: Have you looked into the 'old' native Scala XML library? https://github.com/scala/scala-xml/wiki/Getting-started

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out like below:
First, I have created a function to extract eventId from xml, returning both eventId and xml:

```
val rdd = input.map {x => (geteventId(x) , x)}
```

Then I sorted on eventId and extracted only xml and saved on hdfs:

```
val result = rdd.soryBy(x => x._1).map(x => x._2)
```

geteventId(x) is used by parsing xml to get the value for eventId.